# Prolog : Operator Expected

Tags: prolog

I get the "Operator Expected" error at the end of the two following rules but i can't understand why.

```
testDrivenChecking :-
%Stores all the methods of the projet which are tested by a unit test 
findall(allTestedMethods, 
    (create(allTestMethods, 'method', _, _), 
        addProperty(allTestMethods, 'annotation', 'Test', _, _), %Method created and ensures that it's a test.
        not(delete(allTestMethods, 'method', _, _)), %The test should not be deleted
        addReference(allTestMethods, 'calls', allTestedMethods, _, _),
        not(remReference(allTestMethods, 'calls', allTestedMethods, _, _))), %Ensures that the test keep testing the method
    allTestedMethodsList),
list_to_set(allTestedMethodsList, allTestedMethodSet),

%Stores all the methods of the project which are not tests or main
findall(allMethods, 
    (create(allMethods, 'method', _, _),
        not(addProperty(allMethods, 'annotation', 'Test', _, _)), 
        not(addProperty(allMethods, 'name', 'main', _, _)), 
    allMethodsList),
list_to_set(allMethodsList, allMethodsSet),  

%Intersection gives the set of methods which are not tested in restMethods
intersection(allTestedMethodSet, allMethodSet, restMethods),

%Gives the lengths of each set
length(allTestedMethodSet, LengthTest), 
length(allMethodSet, LengthMethods),
length(restMethods, LengthRest).
```

I've seek for hours but I really can't find why I doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
findall(allMethods, 
        (create(allMethods, 'method', _, _),
         not(addProperty(allMethods, 'annotation', 'Test', _, _)), 
         not(addProperty(allMethods, 'name', 'main', _, _)), 
        allMethodsList),
```

should be:

```
findall(allMethods, 
        (create(allMethods, 'method', _, _),
         not(addProperty(allMethods, 'annotation', 'Test', _, _)), 
         not(addProperty(allMethods, 'name', 'main', _, _))), 
        allMethodsList),
```

Note the additional closing parenthesis in the fourth line.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the `not/1` is a relic of old days. Consider using instead the standard `(\+)/1` built-in predicate.